# Do these inequalities imply these inequalities? (Norms and squaring)

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose we have the inequalities involving norms
$$\lVert f \rVert_{X}^2 \leq C_1(\lVert f \rVert_{Y}^2 + \lVert f \rVert_{Z}^2)$$
and
$$\lVert f \rVert_{X}^2 \geq C_2(\lVert f \rVert_{Y}^2 + \lVert f \rVert_{Z}^2)$$
Does it follow that the inequalities above  are true without the squares, i.e., is it true that
$$\lVert f \rVert_{X} \leq C_3(\lVert f \rVert_{Y} + \lVert f \rVert_{Z})$$
and
$$\lVert f \rVert_{X} \geq C_4(\lVert f \rVert_{Y} + \lVert f \rVert_{Z})$$
Here $X, Y, Z$ are Banach spaces.

Comment: I think the easiest way to get this is to use the fact that any norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.  Here you are comparing the 1-norm and the 2-norm on two numbers.

Comment: @JasonKnapp Nice one, if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.